# Handling touches on an image view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone App development.

I want to perform some operation when I click on an image in an imageview.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: +1 for simple, strait to the point question!

Answer (score 2):

This topic is covered in one of the very first tutorials on how to program for the iPhone, so I'll suggest you try following these.
Basically it's handled by connecting an action in Interface Builder from the imageview to the handler in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIImageView. In the subclass, create a `touchesBegan:withEvent` method. Perform your "some operation" there.

When you create your UIImageView instance, call `setUserInteractionEnabled()` to make it accept touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to add a custom button as subview to imageview of same size as the imageview. It will be like overlaying a invisible button over a imageview. If you touch the imageview it will be like touching the button. Set Button action for the custom button.

Another option is instead of imageview set the background image to a button. set button action for that.

Answer (score -1):

Declare this in your header file:

```
- (void)processTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Then use this in the ***.m** file:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self processTouch:[touches anyObject]];        
}


- (void)processTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"You just touch somewhere on the screen!");
}
```

This code will run the "processTouch" method each time a user touches **ANYWERE** on the iPhone screen. This may not be what you are looking for, but I decided to post it anyway! :D

Comment: He was looking to process a touch when his `UIImageView` was touched, not when `anyObject` was touched.